# Rstudio executing script fragments on startup

Tags: r, rstudio

Brand new Windows 11 Pro machine, latest R (4.3) and Rstudio (2023.12.0).  When I start up Rstudio about 15 statements appear in the Rstudio history pane but not the R console.  Here are the first few:

```
install.packages("Validate")
#Begin Figure 51 
source("wnit.R")
#map the ratings into [0,1]
r = (o - 1)/(5 - 1)
```

$HOME was set in the Win 11 environment, and is different from C:/Users/Bob

These statements come from at least 3 files. The first install stmt is not in any file I can find in the $HOME directory tree.  The .rprofile in $HOME only contains two statements catting "Entering" and "Leaving" to the console.  I've removed any startup memory from last sessions in Global/Options.  $HOME is a directory full of work from the last 10 years.  C:/Users/Bob doesn't seem to have any startup files, and heading further down into AppData/Roaming and /Local hasn't yielded anything.

The last two statements come from files that haven't been used in 2 years and are buried several directories down from $HOME.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you click on the *load* icon in the history panel, you should see which .Rhistory file has been loaded at startup. I suggest deleting that file (and ensure in the global options that history files are not saved). In fact, I just now noticed that I had stuff in the history from years ago (which tells you how often I look at that) and deleted a history file.

Comment: Roland, I think you did it!  For some reason Rstudio was executing the top bit of the .Rhistory file.  When I deleted the .Rhistory file, that stopped.  For fun I restored it, but Rstudio no longer executed from .Rhistory on startup.  So the problem is solved, but a small mystery remains.  Thanks for your help.